# Getting error after updating gradle and android studio to 3.0.0 and android support lib to 26.0.1

Tags: android, gradle

updated **android studio to 3 and gradle to 3.0.0 b**eta getting following

> error: Error:(792) attribute 'android:name' in  tag
>   must be a valid Java class name
>   Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link
>   failed: Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:

Comment: If you were not getting these errors and project was fine before I would recommend that you do a "Invalidate Cache" https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfWNF.png

Comment: after performing invalidate cache also same error

Comment: post your manifest and your build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Had this errors myself earlier and was able to fix by turning off AAP2 for this to work.

Go to your gradle.properties file and add this line to fix this error
`android.enableAapt2=false`.

Got this from [a tweet](https://twitter.com/androidstudio/status/875311569219006464?lang=en) by the Android Studio account.